# Different Wordpress Featured Image Overlay Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a grid of images (created by the featured image of each posts) and would like to have a hover effect applied to each image.

I would like it to display the title of the post with a coloured overlay. The entire image is overlaid/replaced with a coloured background with the post title contained within the image box.

The big thing is though, I would like there to be different coloured backgrounds for each post.

current code (content page.php) -

```
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-4 col-sm-4 pbox '); ?>>
    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 560, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>

    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <div class = "box-ovrly">
      <h2 class="box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <div class="box-meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    </div>

 </article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Struggling to figure out how to overlay in general, then move on to more complicated styling like specific colours. The examples I found use the link tags 'hover' effect but I can't manipulate that to work for me

ex.

```
<a href="#" id="box-ovrly"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-    todb82eBRF4/T2iE-lgY2LI/AAAAAAAABNo/HMhNfppjrHg/s1600/reddit%2Balien.JPG">    <p>REDDIT!</p></a>
```

with the hover absolute positioned over the image

Comment: Without seeing your CSS, we wouldn't know what have you achieved so far because the whole effect is handled through CSS. Are you having problem with generating different background colours, or problem with hover effect in general? Your question isn't so clear and the former would be a problem with JS / PHP since CSS alone can't be 'dynamic'.

Comment: updated to show more relevant code I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want, Notice the applied CSS. As Well:

```
// Generate Random Color
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

$('article').hover( 
    function () {
        var color = getRandomColor();
        $('.box-ovrly', this).addClass('ovrly_start');
        $('.box-ovrly', this).css('background', color);        
    }, 
    function() {
       $('.box-ovrly', this).removeClass('ovrly_start');
    }
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/jdr1y2Lq/)

Comment: thats awesome! is there any way to control the colours though. Like I can pick which colour each post gets

Comment: Best options for this is to create a custom box in add/edit post section and apply the picked color there, then access that color while fetching the featured image.

Comment: for the code you mentioned, do I add it to my functions.php file or do I have to call it a different way?

Comment: follow with this example, and apply the codes in your functions.php file https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box